# Gradle project for plain Java and Android with single source tree

Tags: java, android, swing, gradle, build.gradle

I'm running project which includes both plain Java (Swing UI) and Android parts, basically source tree consisting 3 parts:

```
         |---swing  (30% of code)
         |
 src-----|---common (40% of code)
         |
         |---android (30% of code)
```

How should I define gradle project(s) in order to build from the same sources 2 different apps - one for Java/Swing another one for Android?

I tried different approaches but in the end failed...

**Update**

If one'd consider 2 or more projects with independent source trees - no problem to implement it - there're number of examples.

Or if to consider 2 projects with the same source tree using the same compiler, again it works with Gradle.

Problem is in implementing gradle project utilizing different compilers on the same source tree.

Answer (score 0):

Setup 3 modules and import these modules as you want via the settings.gradle files. For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html