# How to share code between Eclipse Swing/maven and Androidstudio / gradle project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I am an experienced Java developer with years of familarity with Eclipse and Maven.

My goal is to create an android application and I am getting familiar with the latest Development environment Android Studio 2.3.2 which obviously uses Java 8 and Gradle. The app shall share code with an Eclipse based project that uses maven and Swing and is also Java 8 based. I am intending to publish the result as an open source project on github.

I found e.g.

- https://github.com/uhafner/android-config as an example but that seems to be outdated.
- https://github.com/cgeo/cgeo - which explictly states that eclipse is only used for codewriting/testing
- [Gradle project for plain Java and Android with single source tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760041/gradle-project-for-plain-java-and-android-with-single-source-tree) suggests an answer for a gradle only approach that has a tutorial link as an answer (which is not accepted) and no example
- https://github.com/javadev/calc which is purely maven driven and has two pom.xml files
- https://github.com/adrian/upm-swing and https://github.com/adrian/upm-android simply have copied subdirectories instead of any kind of shared config management

**How feasible is a combined maven/gradle project structure?**

**What would be a proper way to structure the project files to accomplish the above goals?**

**What are good examples projects that follow a similar approach?**

My reason to be reluctant with Gradle and IntelliJ is obvious. It is an unfamiliar environment for me and android is *not*  the main target of my development.

Comment: Gradle provides the same features as Maven. Eclipse can work with Gradle... So why do you need Maven? And why do you need Eclipse? Just use Intellij / Android Studio

Comment: thx for your comment - so you are suggesting to only use one gradle layout?  Please supply a link to an example structure or project with the shared code approach for a Swing Application and Android App. e.g. as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760041/gradle-project-for-plain-java-and-android-with-single-source-tree

Comment: You just start a new Gradle module with `apply plugin: 'java'` for the swing code. I don't have a link other than the official Gradle documentation for the Java plugin

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer seems be covered at:

[Can Android Studio be used to run standard Java projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626810/can-android-studio-be-used-to-run-standard-java-projects)

I got somewhat of a success with the project https://github.com/BITPlan/can4eve
but would appreciate some help on the android studio / gradle side of things.

The project also has travis support built in and I am also running nightly Jenkins checks based on maven.